# Button Insert on Oracle Forms

Tags: sql, forms, oracleforms

I made a form on Oracle Forms which contain for textareas: CIN (it's PK), Name, Age, Adress
In part of database, I have the table Person with the same fields.

My goal is to insert data from this Form into the table Person on clicking on the Insert Button developed by me with this code:

```
insert into personne values(:personne.name,:personne.age,:personne.adresse,:personne.cin);
```

the probem is that when I fill in the form with new data and clicking on Insert Button this error is appeared : ORA 00001: constrain violation , even though I cleared the table from data in advance

Anybody have an idea ?

thanks in advance

Comment: do you perform a commit in the trigger and is the block based on the database table personne? Then by that commit oracle inserts the row into the database and you do the same, which delivers a ORA-00001

Comment: Generally speaking, you do not need to manually perform `insert` statements in Oracle Forms. Just create a `block` that is based on your database table, and let the normal Oracle Forms behavior handle inserts/updates/etc.

Comment: Do you have any other code in your button? Most likely the issue is as nightfox79 and GriffeyDog wrote but hard to say without more details.

Answer (score 0):

as Griffey said, the best way to do this insert , is creating the block based on the table, so Oracle forms autmatically will control the DML process.

the error means, that you are trying to insert the same PK to more that 1 record, so you could try:
1- creating an sequence to automatically generate the pk field (from oracle forms or via a before insert trigger in the database, so when the PK is null, you assign a value using the sequence)

2- before insert use a message to display the value of the pk field. :
message('cin : '|| :personne.cin);

if you will like me to help you via remote, just let me know.